# 2010 unit circles

Tags: geometry

$C$ is a unit circle with radius $r$. $C_1,C_2,\ldots, C_{2010}$ are unit circles along the circumference of $C$ touching $C$ externally. Also the pairs $C_1C_2;C_2C_3,\ldots;C_{2010}C_1$ touch. Then find $r$. Options:

1) $cosec(\pi/2010)$

2) $sec(\pi/2010)$

3) $cosec(\pi/2010)-1$

4) $sec(\pi/2010)-1$

I try solving but I am getting a weird angle. A picture might help. Thank you.

Comment: If $C$ is a unit circle with radius $r$, then I would usually go with $r=1$... Why don't you double check if $C$ really a unit circle?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Made it before I noticed its already done, but anyway here it is...

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's a picture.   The right triangle has hypotenuse $\ldots$, one angle $\ldots$, and the opposite side $\ldots$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: n no. of circles]

The generalized formula for n. no of circles each with a radius $R$ & touching one another along the circumference of a circle with a radius $r$ (above diagram is only for visualization) is given as follows
$$\bbox[4pt, border: 1px solid blue;]{r=R\left[cosec\frac{\pi}{n}-1\right]}$$
where, $n$ is a natural number $n\geq3$

Above formula can be easily derived by joining the centers $C_1, C_2, C_3, \!  \cdots \! ....,C_{n-1}, C_n$ of all the circles & analyzing the polygon obtained

Now, for 2010 unit circles, substitute $n=2010$ & $R=1$ in the above generalized formula, we can easily find out the radius $r$ of circle C as follows
$$r=R\left[cosec\frac{\pi}{n}-1\right]=(1)\left[cosec\frac{\pi}{2010}-1\right]=cosec\frac{\pi}{2010}-1$$

Hence the option (3) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess:

The $2010$ centers are uniformly spread on a circle of radius $r+1$, so there will most probably be a $-1$ term. And the trigonometric function must be a $\text{cosec}$ as it needs to go to $\infty$ as $2010$ is increased.

My bet for $3$.